# WiFi Adapter does not work on Linux, works perfectly on Windows

Tags: wifi, drivers

My WiFi adapter model is **Netis WF2123** and it has an **RTL8192FU** chip. It's working perfectly on **Windows** just after connecting, but I can't make it work on **Ubuntu**. I have tried almost everything, downloaded every driver repo on GitHub that I've come across it's still not working.

Can someone help me, please? Someone with a similar chip using Linux is appreciated.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `just after connecting`

Comment: try knoppix live ... http://knoppix.net/

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/blackPantherOS/rtl8192fu ?

Comment: @JeremyBoden, what's the use in reading it?

Comment: Apparently someone got very pissed off:- The CLOSED DEVELOMENT - rtl8192fu

Comment: Try to build official drivers from site https://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/de_details/id/1/de/89.html. They've drivers with installation script for Linux distributions. May be you'll need to install kernel-headers and dev-tools for your distribution

Comment: @JeremyBoden I know, someone deleted the German wiki page of the Blackpanther OS, so they decided to delete the repo of the open-source driver of RTL8192FU.

Comment: @jsotola on windows the drivers are installed automatically after connecting.

Comment: @spybull That's the first thing I did. It gives me: Compile make driver error : 2